# PostgreSQL: fill column with quotient of two other columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

My PostgreSQL table (scrapes) has a column, which I would like to fill with the quotient of two other columns in the same table. The below didn't work and I am having difficulty finding the right command.

```
UPDATE scrapes SET priceEUR = sale_price / fxtoEUR;
```

The error message is:

```
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "scrapes.fxtoEUR".
```

The below didn't work either.

```
SELECT sales_price, fxtoEUR, (sales_price / fxtoEUR) AS priceEUR FROM scrapes;
```

Same error message. Sorry, if this is really obvious, but can't see it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column name contains uppercase letters and was double quoted when you created it, so it is now case sensitive and you must double quote the field name.

```
SELECT sales_price, "fxtoEUR", (sales_price / "fxtoEUR") AS priceEUR FROM scrapes;
```